# How to make configurable makefile and optional configuration for certain files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've made makefile that makes printable version of presentations.

How it works:

1. makes tiles for each presentation
2. concatenates presentations into one big file
3. not done yet: add numbers to pages

The `Makefile`:

```
SLIDES_BASE_NAME := presentation-prefix-

FILES := $(shell ls $(SLIDES_BASE_NAME)*.pdf)

OUT_DIR := generated
SLIDES_DIR := $(OUT_DIR)/slides
SLIDES := $(addprefix $(SLIDES_DIR)/, $(FILES))
SLIDES_CONCAT := $(OUT_DIR)/slides-oneside-print.pdf

CFG_FILE := config.env

TRIM := 0 0.36cm 0 0
# TODO: read global config

$(SLIDES_DIR)/%.pdf : %.pdf
    @echo Generating: $< "->" $@
    @# TODO: read optional local config - "$<.cfg"
    @pdfjam --nup 2x4 $< --outfile $@ --delta "0.1cm 0.1cm" --a4paper --frame True --trim "$(TRIM)" --clip True --width '9.45cm'; 

all: $(SLIDES_CONCAT)

$(SLIDES_CONCAT): $(SLIDES)
    @echo Generating: $@ from $^
    @pdfjam $(SLIDES) -o $@

$(SLIDES): | $(SLIDES_DIR)

$(SLIDES_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(SLIDES_DIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OUT_DIR)
```

I would like to make it configurable. See "TODO" in Makefile.

How can I add global config file:

- reads property TRIM (more properties are about to come, so can't use `TRIM := $(shell cat ...)` ).
- when global config file changes, and I run `make`, then everything gets remade.

Some professors have inconsistent style of presentations, so: How can I add optional config for each file:

- properties are overridden from config
- not required, but if present and changed - causes rebuild of certain presentation

I've been thinking about changind rule:
`$(SLIDES_DIR)/%.pdf : %.pdf` that it will depend on global cfg, and optionaly depend on optional config file for current presentation, then wrap contents of rule into my own script and pass all filenames to that script.

However, I don't know what is the proper way to do that. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started along the way. They configuration file will have be be written of course in the Make language.

So you'd start out by using ["include"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html#index-including-other-makefiles). You'll see that you can set include names from variables or filename patterns so that gives a way for a local filename to optional or conditionally used.

You'll need to pay attention to where the include occurs with relation to the things it controls. And you'll probably have to switch from using `:=` (expand in the macro) to `=` (expand when the variable is used)

As for making sure things change when the configuration file changes, that's just having the configuration files be a dependency of the things that have to get run when that changes. I put that in as a variable below so you don't have to list all of the configuration files, local, global, and so on.

In the autoconf system, for example, `config.status` and `config.h` are such a configuration files; so see how that works in the autoconf system by looking at one of the makefiles configure generates.

---

Here is a small example to get you started. Let say all of these files are in the same directory. Create global configuration makefile called `global-config.mk` with this:

```
 TRIM = 0 0.72cm 0 0
```

and optional local configuration file called `local-config.mk` with this:

```
 LOCAL_USED=yep
```

Now in your main Makefile will have among other things this structure:

```
TRIM = 0 0.36cm 0 0  # used if not in any config file
LOCAL_USED=nope 
local_config=$(wildcard local-config.mk) # optional config
CONFIG_FILES=global-config.mk $(local_config)
include global-config.mk $(CONFIG_FILES)

slides: $(CONFIG_FILES)  # and other dependencies here
    @echo trim is $(TRIM)
    @echo local used $(LOCAL_USED)
```

Now try running `make slides`. I get:

```
$ make slides
trim is 0 0.72cm 0 0
local used yep
```

They try it after commenting out the line in `global-config.mk`:

```
# TRIM = 0 0.72cm 0 0
```

I get:

```
$ make slides
trim is 0 0.36cm 0 0
local used yep
```

Finally remove `local-config.mk`. I get:

```
$ make slides
trim is 0 0.36cm 0 0
local used nope
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's hard to get what are you pointing to, because I'm beginner with Makefiles. Could you provide some example, please? Just some `echo-ing` into files instead of real pdf transformation.